# Whole house fan motor size

Tags: attic, exhaust-fan, electric-motor

I am told that my whole house fan motor is no longer repairable. It is a 1/2 HP Robbins & Myers dating from 1966 and weighs about 51#. The Hunter fan documentation says the motor is the right size for the fan, which is 42" in diameter. The motor repair place claims that to get the necessary power in a new motor, I should upgrade to 1 HP. Why would that be?

Comment: Are you asking us why someone else said something? Seems like a question for _them_.

Comment: Your wording suggests that you've had to repair the motor previously, implying that it's failed a few times already.  You might be able to answer your own question based on the failure mode(s) of the motor (windings, bearings, capacitor if equipped, starter+start windings if equipped).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge motor HP has not changed. I would go with the manufacturer's recommendations, the original motor lasted over 50 years. If you go to a 1HP motor the shaft size will probably change. You also need to consider the electrical side of this. Is the fan electrical feed large enough to operate a 1 HP motor? Are the thermostat and switches rated for that HP they have to be rated for the 1 HP rating you will need. A 15A breaker is OK for 1/2 HP however a 20A breaker is borderline for a 1HP motor. Breaker is sized at least 1.25 times the full motor load. Is it direct drive or pulley driven. With the above I would ask them to explain why the larger motor and what would the advantage be. You already know you get a lot of life from a 1/2 HP motor.

Answer (score 2):

When I had to replace the fan motor on my whole house fan I increased the HP to the next size which in my case was a 3/4HP motor. My professional opinion is that most older motors would actually produce more HP than advertised. Also, to make my fan more user friendly, I installed a 2 speed motor that had to have a 2 speed switch and wiring change that would yield a lower air flow at a much reduced noise level for say when running the fan at night when you are trying to sleep. My wife was pleased and thanked me for the exhaust fan upgrade.

Comment: You did this but provide no evidence that your wiring was up to code for the rated power

Comment: Pardon me, @Carl Witthoft, I didn't know that I had to write a complete essay on the change I made. I was just telling the OP what I did and that it performed well. And why yes, I had a registered electrician do the work so I knew it was up to "code" in my area.

Comment: @dg when you throw in "professional opinion" then one expects some professional substantiation.  All you had to say was that a licensed pro did the install, and state whether rewiring or a change in breaker was required

Answer (score 1):

Eventhough older motors say 1/4 horspower or 1/2 horsepower they could often handle more than they were rated for and were more powerful.
When replacing an old 1/4 horsepower motor you will likely need go up a size if it's an older home.
I've had to replace a 1/4 Hp motor with a modern 1/2 Hp motor to have the fan function correctly.
The ratings and classifications of motors has changed over the years and is not accurate. A less energy efficient motor from the old days could be pushed beyond it's rated power. Modern motors are more energy efficient and weaker so they can barely do what they are listed for. The ratings from the past are irrelvant to modern ratings.
Be aware that a larger motor consumes more power and that the circuit breaker, and wire will be tasked with providing more power to a larger motor.

Comment: This sounds like it's simply a rewording of d.george's answer from more than a year ago. If you'll take the [tour] and browse the [help] (especially the part on answering), you'll see that we expect a bit more than that around here.

Answer (score -2):

It has to do with the coating on the windings. Older motors, 50 etc years ago had a coating that would not be EPA compliant today and it would last a long time under load. The stuff used today, just won’t take the heat and the windings burn and fail. It’s as simple as that.

Comment: You could improve your answer by quoting a reference